# Convert Word File to PDF Using Adobe PDF Services API and Node.js

Tags: node.js, adobe

I have this script that is not working -- can anyone please let me know where I'm going wrong:

I'm on a Plesk server... I'm getting no logs or anything. Don't know why. I'm new to Node.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const PDFServicesSdk = require('@adobe/pdfservices-node-sdk');
const winston = require('winston');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Create the logs directory if it doesn't exist
const logsDirectory = 'logs';
if (!fs.existsSync(logsDirectory)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logsDirectory);
}

// Configure Winston logging to save errors and logs to mylogs.txt
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
     new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/myerrorlogs.txt', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/mylogs.txt' }),
  ],
});

// Use morgan for logging HTTP requests
app.use(morgan('combined'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/generate-pdf', async (req, res) => {
  const jsonDataForMerge = req.body;

  try {
    // Initial setup, create credentials instance.
    const credentials = PDFServicesSdk.Credentials
      .servicePrincipalCredentialsBuilder()
      .withClientId('CLIENT ID')
      .withClientSecret('CLIENT SECRET')
      .build();

    // Setup input data for the document merge process
    // const jsonString = fs.readFileSync('ra-data.json'),
    // const jsonDataForMerge = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    // Create an ExecutionContext using credentials
    const executionContext = PDFServicesSdk.ExecutionContext.create(credentials);

    // Create a new DocumentMerge options instance
    const documentMerge = PDFServicesSdk.DocumentMerge;
    const documentMergeOptions = documentMerge.options;
    const options = new documentMergeOptions.DocumentMergeOptions(jsonDataForMerge, documentMergeOptions.OutputFormat.PDF);

    // Create a new operation instance using the options instance
    const documentMergeOperation = documentMerge.Operation.createNew(options);

    // Set operation input document template from a source file.
    const input = PDFServicesSdk.FileRef.createFromLocalFile('complete-ra-template.docx');
    documentMergeOperation.setInput(input);

    // Generating a file name
    let outputFilePath = createOutputFilePath();

    // Execute the operation and Save the result to the specified location.
    documentMergeOperation.execute(executionContext)
      .then(result => result.saveAsFile(outputFilePath))
      .catch(err => {
        logger.error('Exception encountered while executing operation', err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error 1');
      });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Caught an error:', err);
  logger.error('Explicit error:', err);
    
    logger.error('Exception encountered while executing operation', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error 2');
  }
});

function createOutputFilePath() {
  let date = new Date();
  let dateString = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
    ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "T" + ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + "-" +
    ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  return ("output/MergeDocumentToPDF/merge" + dateString + ".pdf");
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

It works fine if I strip away all the server stuff and just run from the console... Creates the PDF without issue, however as soon as I put it on and make a request through https I get a 500.